# Tableau - Lock 2 datasource blending settings

Tags: locking, datasource, tableau-api, blending

I'm using Tableau 10.1 and have defined a workbook which use 2 datasources (an Oracle connection and a Salesforce connection), which have been put in relationship to each other by the 'Edit Relationship' function.

Since this procedure makes 'a sort of' join operation between the two datasources, I'd like to save the two connected datasources into a single entity or, if this is not possible, to 'lock' somehow the relationship settings.

My objective is, in fact, to make the two datasources available on a tableau server to other members of my organization, but they should find the data ready and must not be able to modify the relationship.

So: is it possible to create a single datasource by them (consider that one of them is a Salesforce connection, and the multi-connection feature is not available)? Is it possible to 'lock' the data blending in a way that no one can modify the relationship by them? Making available an empty workbook with the right blending settings doesn't look a good solution to me...

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on version 10.1, use cross-database joins instead. This allows you to create a single data source, publish it like you want, but it will include the join between two different databases.

Comment: unfortunately for salesforce it's not possible until 10.2